# How can I change the ssl port number for my asp.net mvc web application inside Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

I have two web applications that are both using the same ssl port number `https://localhost:44300/`; which doesn't allow me to run both of them at once.

How can I change the port number for one of the web applications to use port number `44301`?

---

I right clicked on the project, then I clicked on the `Web` tab but this will only allow me to change the http port and not the https port.

Comment: right click project -> properties ->Web -> Project Url and put Project Url as https ://localhost:44301/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To complement Dandy's answer comment, this is a picture of the section where you can make changes relating to the server/port you want to use for your app. You can also select if you want to use a local IIS server or a remote host.

[image]